# How to prevent fragment identifiers from showing in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fragment-identifier

I have a link like this

```
    <a href="#login_form">Log in</a>
```

after clicking on the link the url changes from

```
   http:/domain.com
```

to

```
   http://domain.com#login_form
```

and a login form pops up.
But i do not want hash tag to be displayed in url. How to do this using java script? No java script used to display login form which pops up.

The login form is something like this.

```
    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>
    <div class="box">
    <h2>LOG IN</h2>
    <form name="login" action="" method="post">
    </form>
    </div>
```

OK. HERE IS THE JS FIDDLE. PLEASE CHECK.

http://jsfiddle.net/vq24P/1/

Comment: Show us your current javascript code.

Comment: no. cannot change href value. it must be same.

Comment: @RahilWazir I have not used any java script for this.

Comment: oh sorry about that. my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a document fragment, not a hash tag, but whatevs.

If, as you say, "no java script [is] used to display login form", I can only assume you're using the CSS `:target` psuedo-class to toggle visibility? In that case, there's nothing you can do. The fragment MUST be in the URL for that element to show up.

Instead, use some JavaScript to do the toggling for you. Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('login_form').style.display = 'block');">Log in</a>
```

(WARNING: Extremely bad example, but it should get the general idea working)

You will need to use `id="login"` instead of `name="login"`

Comment: `.overlay:target` was the kind of thing I'm talking about. There is *no way* for this to work without it appearing in the URL.

Comment: can't it be removed from url after showing up by java script?

Comment: Yes, but you would at best have `http://example.com/#` in the end, and then the form wouldn't be the target any more and it'd disappear again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i checked similar posts. so this can't be done.