# HTML Arrow "Top of Site" dont show #id in the URL

Tags: html, css

I use a simple arrow at the end of my page to link back to the to of the page

`<a class="arrow-up" href="#menu-tophomesitemapsearchlanguageswitcher"></a>`

If the user clicks on that arrow the page goes to Top as wanted, because the element with the id `#menu-tophomesitemapsearchlanguageswitcher` is in the Header.

But you can see it in the Browser ULR `URL/#menu-tophomesitemapsearchlanguageswitcher`
is there a way to hide that the id of the element where i did `href` to is appedned to my URL.

Just that the common user doesnt see it :)

Comment: Use jQuery to scroll on top instead

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364869/how-to-prevent-fragment-identifiers-from-showing-in-url

Comment: ok sry did not find this other question, but I will give JQuery a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery:

`jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');`

Combined it looks like this:

`<a class="arrow-up" onclick="jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use some vanilla JS? E.g.:

```
<a href='#' onclick='event.preventDefault();document.body.scrollTop=0;'>To Top!</a>
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sr3wr67/)